# MYSQL select last 3 rows, order by ASC

Tags: php, mysql, select, sql-order-by

I just want to select the newest 3 comments on a post, and have them ordered in ASC order.

This selects the last 3 rows, however I need them in the reverse order:

```
mysql_query("
SELECT * FROM comments WHERE postID='$id' AND state='0' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 3")
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can reverse sort it later.

```
SELECT * 
FROM (SELECT * FROM comments
      WHERE postID='$id' 
        AND state='0' 
      ORDER BY id DESC 
      LIMIT 3) t
ORDER BY id ASC;
```

Comment: It's not recommended that you use *, it's faster to mention all items

Comment: @MarcAlexander: just gives a name to the subquery, as if it were a real table. Not used here, but it's a good habit to have (IMHO).

Comment: it is helpful but how can i do it in this php function which i have:    `code
       $tblNews_new = new Tbl('last_news');
       $newseObject = $tblNews_new->Find([['tbl'=>'last_news','field'=>'news_type','value'=>'1']]);
       foreach($newseObject as $item):`code`

Answer (score 1):

This can also be done just in PHP, without modifying the SQL query, by simply iterating backwards through the result set:

```
$res = mysql_query(...);
for($i=mysql_num_rows($res)-1; $i>=0; $i--) {
    //do whatever
}
```

I confess I don't know what the performance difference is (if any), but it's just another option that might suite you.

Comment: I prefer this method, I think it separates the idea of selecting three newest and outputting oldest first better (in my mind at least :p)

Comment: Well it's always best to do as much work on the server as you can (in the database), and not having the user end have to do this (with php), but I do thank you for your answer.

Comment: I think it really comes down to a matter of preference.  I usually like to do as much in SQL as possible, but sometimes it can confuse the code, whereas the PHP is much more readable and understandable, IMHO, so sometimes iterating backwards just makes it much more clear what is actually going on in the code.

Comment: Adding to what cegfault said, doing it with PHP is perfectly fine for most websites, however when you have high user traffic every bit of speed you can save adds up.

Answer (score -1):

> SELECT * FROM comments LIMT((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM comments)-2,3) ORDER
> BY id;

As LIMIT's first argument(OffSet) start from 0th index, and second arguments gives the no. of records should be picked up.

Comment: Did you try this code yourself?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -3):

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM messeges WHERE username='{$_SESSION['username']}' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 3) t ORDER BY id ASC");
```

Comment: Code-only answers do very little to educate SO readers.  Please edit your answer to include some explanation. Your answer is in the moderation queue because it has been flagged as low-quality.   (...and please format your code)