# Reverse while loop

Tags: php

```php
    while($data=$SQL->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
       echo $data=['message'];
   }
```

is that possible to reverse while loop?
I have a page echo out messages and I need put in reverse

SQL- DESC LIMIT 20
fetch last 20 messages

but my chat box is print in reverse

```
message 1 (oldest message)
message 2
message 3 (newest message)
```

Comment: Why not just order your SQL query?

Comment: You can also put the result in an array first, and then reverse the array, but i think it's better if you use @BenFortune's solution.

Comment: @HenkJansen Adjusting the query should be preferred especially for large datasets, as it can become a performance problem there.

Comment: possible duplicate of [MYSQL select last 3 rows, order by ASC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8891060/mysql-select-last-3-rows-order-by-asc). Have a look at the accepted answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should define the order of the data set in your original SQL query.

[See documentation](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_orderby.asp) for the ORDER BY clause.

> **Update**

It seems that the OP wants the 20 newest messages, but ordered in reverse. Then you need to perform a subquery like this:

```
SELECT `message` 
FROM (SELECT * FROM `table`
      ORDER BY `id` DESC 
      LIMIT 20) AS `i`
ORDER BY `i`.`id` ASC;
```

Comment: the problem is, i fetch DESC last 20 messages, but my chat box is reverse

Comment: when query desc, it put newest message on top, but i need it at bottom

Answer (score 1):

After fetching records You can just reverse your returned array

https://www.php.net/array_reverse

Comment: a query does not return an array.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to reverse the data in PHP, you can use `array_reverse`:

```
// Fetch all records 
$data = $SQL->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

// Reverse them
$data = array_reverse($data);

foreach ($data as $record) {
    echo $record['message'];
}
```

Although I would recommend ordering in SQL, as it will be faster.