# Most Recent Entries in PHP/MySQL Ordered by Ascending

Tags: php, mysql, sorting

I would like to display the seven most recent entries, but I want the entries sorted in ascending order using PHP/MySQL. This is my current code:

```
$sql="SELECT date, weight, COUNT(*) AS 'count' FROM weights GROUP BY date ORDER BY date ASC";
```

Note: I have tried adding "LIMIT 7," but that will only show entries 1-7 (not, say 15-21, which is what I want).

Also note: I have tried searching on Stack Overflow and Google, but the code didn't work.

Comment: `LIMIT 15, 7` would show you 15 - 21

Comment: You can read more here https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html. `With two arguments, the first argument specifies the offset of the first row to return, and the second specifies the maximum number of rows to return.`

Comment: I'm asking for the most recent seven entries, not a paricular range like 15-21.

Answer (score 0):

I got this to work thanks to some other Stack Overflow threads.

Note: My code is slightly different.

This is my code:

```
$sql="SELECT id, date, weight FROM (SELECT id, date, weight, COUNT(*) AS 'count' FROM weights GROUP BY date ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 7) t ORDER BY id ASC";
```

References:

[MYSQL select last 3 rows, order by ASC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8891060/mysql-select-last-3-rows-order-by-asc)

[Select last 20 order by ascending - PHP/MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5912770/select-last-20-order-by-ascending-php-mysql)

---

Note: I do not know the difference between...

```
t ORDER BY id ASC
```

and...

```
tmp order by tmp.id asc
```

I went with the first one, because it happened to be the first one I got to work (this took a while) and it looked simpler.

If anyone knows if the GROUP BY and ORDER BY values are correct, please comment.

Please also comment to let me know which version of the ASC I should use.